# Add "Post as anonymous" checkbox to forum topic creation

Tags: nodes

is it possible to add a post as anonymous checkbox to the topic creation in drupal forum?

I can also provide a user if not a string via which the content should be submitted. Basically I don't want users to need to logout but directly from their account create a disguise username or anything that would resemble this functionality.

Thanks! Jan

Comment: Do you want a post not to be associated with user at all, or you want to just hide his name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/project/forum_cloakpost
This module allows registered users to post to a forum as an anonymous user, via a checkbox on the add node/comment page.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Anonymous Posting](https://www.drupal.org/project/anonymous_posting) module, which will do your requirement exactly

> Anonymous Posting is a Drupal module that allow anonymous users to
>   fill their contact informations (name, email and homepage) when
>   posting any content type including Forum Topics. Then the submitted
>   name will be shown instead of the usual generic defined anonymous
>   string.

[image]